# how do I get exact type from a generic that is extending a function?

Tags: typescript

For the following code:

```
function HomeAnimals (owner : string) {
    return {
        dog : `${owner}'s golden retriever`,
        cat : `${owner}'s persian`
    };
}
function ExoticAnimals (owner : string) {
    return {
        snake : `${owner}'s brown`,
    }
}
function Example<T extends (owner : string) => unknown> (owner : string, Animals : T) {
    return {
        owner : owner,
        animals : Animals(owner)
    }
}

const a = Example("bob", HomeAnimals);
```

how can I rewrite it so that code completion can get me `a.animals.dog` instead of remaining as `a.animals : unknown` right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your generic parameter `T` to be the return type of the function instead:

```
function Example<T>(
    owner: string,
    Animals: (owner: string) => T
) {
    return {
        owner: owner,
        animals: Animals(owner),
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACTgWwKYEEwzQQwBsBnACjgHcwMAnALkWKhpjAHMBKRAbwChEBiGhiggaSPoKmIAJnDYMABgBJulajQC+AcmKI2cQjIxJhzGBgButRQBp+0gRHxQlq9bR16ADrWIx8MDsHAU0Abl5NXlBIWAREAFEADzhYCBw8IjIPekZzdi5JQTMxCRDpYjB8AGsMNzUqT11EACMadWCpcMjeaPBoeCRk-DRvQgwAHgAVAD5ScpyGJhZ2eykMghIGckbc5dZORABeGcQp3kLykvEecqlFxBy1x0RAzK3EDaydjQ5n0IiUV4EAQTFex0SSRGYwwpAARC04C04bYUOhsLhNsQOBEgA)

Comment: I thought I would have to feed the exact content into T, but it seems to work out the details from the input